# Pack files using c so that can be unpacked to original files

Tags: c

I have to pack few files in such a way so that at some later stage i can unpack them again to the original files using c program, please suggest.

Comment: Have you ever heard of "zip"?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the explanation for wanting to write your own implementation might be curiosity.

Whether you add compression or not, if you simply want to store files in an archive, similar to the `tar` command, then you have a few possible approaches.

One of the fundamental choices you have to make is: how to demarcate the boundaries of the packed files within the archive?  It is not a great idea to use a special character, because the packed files could contain any character to begin with.

To keep track of the end of files, you can use the length of the file in bytes.  For example, you could, for each file:

1. Write to the archive the '\0' terminated C-string which names the packed file.
2. Write to the archive an off64_t which gives the length, in bytes, of the packed file.
3. Write to the archive the actual bytes (if any) of the packed file.
4. (Optional) Write to the archive a checksum or CRC of the packed file.

Repeatedly perform this for each file, concatenating the results with no intervening characters.

Finally, when no files remain, write an empty C-string, a zero character.

The unpacking process is:

1. Read the '\0'-terminated C-string which names this packed file.
2. If the name is empty, assert that we have read the entire archive, then exit.
3. Read the off64_t which gives the length of the packed file.
4. Read as many bytes as the packed file length from the archive and write to the newly-created unpacked file.

Again, repeat these steps until step (2) concludes the program.

This design, in which file names alternate with file data is workable.  It has some drawbacks.  The essential problem is that the data structure isn't designed for random access.  In order to get the information about a file in the "middle" of the archive, a program is required to process the preceding files.  The program can call `lseek_64` to skip reading program data that isn't needed, but a processor needs to read at least each file name and each file length.  The file length is needed to skip over the file data.  The file name, as I arranged the data, must be read in order to locate the file length.

So this is inefficient.  Even if the file names did not have to be read in order to access file size, the fact that the file details are sprinkled throughout the archive mean that reading the index data requires accessing several ranges of data on the disk.

A better approach might be to write a "block" of index data to the front of the file.  This data structure might be something like:

1. The size of the first file in the archive.
2. The name of the first file in the archive.
3. The position, in bytes, within this archive, where the "first file" may be located as a contiguous block of bytes.
4. The size of the second file in the archive...

And the data in the index might repeat until, again, a file with empty name marks the end of the index.

Having an index like this is nice, but presents a difficulty: when the user wishes to append a file to the archive, the index might need to grow in size.  This could change the locations of the packed files within the archive -- the archive program may need to move them around to make room for a bigger index.

The file structure can get more and more complex in order to serve all these different needs.  For example, the index can be designed so that it is always allocated out of what the file system considers a "page" (the amount the OS reads or writes from the disk as a minimum-size granule), and if the index needs to grow, discontiguous "index pages" are chained together by file-position data leading from one index page to another.  (Like a linked list, but on disk.)  The complexity can go on and on.

Answer (score 1):

A fast solution would be to take advantage of an external library like [zLib](http://zlib.net) (usage example: http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html ) and use it for compression.

If you want to dig deeper into the topic of compression, have a look at the different lossless compression algorithms and further hints at [Wikipedia - Data compression](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Data_compression).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tar like program a couple of day ago, here my implementation (hope you can get some ideas):
Each file is stored in the file archive with an "header", which is like:

```
<file-type,file-path,file-size,file-mode>
```

in file-type i used 0 for files and 1 for directories (in this way you can recreate the directories tree)
For example, the header of a file named foo.txt of size 245 bytes with mode 0755 (on unix, see chmod) will looks like:

```
<0,foo.txt,245,0755>
here the file contents
```

in this way, the first character of the file archive is always a <, then you parse the list separated by commas (first possible bug) and extract the file type, the path, the size (which you will use to read the next *size* bytes from the archive - to avoid the "special character bug" pointed out by Heath Hunnicutt) and the mode of the file (let's say you have a binary file and you want to have it executable when extracted too, you need to chmod it with the original file mode).

About the first possible bug, a comma is not commonly used in a file name, but it's probably better to use another character or "sanitize" the path with a couple "" (sorry i don't remeber the name now, and english is not my mother tongue), obviously the parser should be aware of it, and ignore any comma in the "".

For writing and reading files in C see fgetc and fputc from stdio.h
To get file infos, chmod and directories tree see stat and chmod from sys/stat.h and ftw from ftw.h (probably linux/unix only, because is a system call).

Hope it helps! (if you need some code i can post some snippets, the header parsing is probably the hardest part).